# glCreateShader Fails over remote connection

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to run an OpenGl program on an Amazon EC2 instance. When run on local computers it works fine, but when run through the remote desktop the program crashes and I've narrowed it down to the `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)` call.

I researched this previously when running over remote desktop on a computer in the local network and the solution I found was to use a batch script that disconnected the session and started the OpenGL exe. Then when you logged back on it was fine. `tscon 1 /dest:console`

Unfortunately now this seems not to work when trying to run on the Amazon instance. Does anyone have any experience with OpenGL issues over remote connections?

Comment: How does it fail? What error does it return? Are shaders even supported when running remotely? (Check for `ARB_vertex_shader`)

Comment: Do you have the capability of writing your own code for this system? The very first thing I would do is query the `GL_VERSION`, `GL_VENDOR` and `GL_RENDERER` strings at run-time.

Comment: So I added in a check to output the OpenGL version and it said it was running v1.1, so that makes sense that the shaders would fail, but the instance I'm using is a g2.2xlarge which amazon says "High-performance NVIDIA GPU with 1,536 CUDA cores and 4GB of video memory" Checking the device manager (this is all on a windows machine) it seems that the graphics card isn't recognized as if the drivers are not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glCreateShader` is one of the functions which location must be obtained at runtime using a `…gl…GetProcAddress` call. This call will give a valid pointer only if the function is actually supported by the installed OpenGL driver. Also even if the function is supported by the driver, the actual feature accessed by the function may not be supported by the device/OpenGL context you're using.

It's mandatory you're checking the validity of the function address `assert(glCreateShader);` and that the function is actually supported (OpenGL version >= OpenGL-2.0 or `GL_ARB_vertex_shader` and `GL_ARB_fragment_shader` in the list of extensions).

> I'm trying to run an OpenGl program on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Virtual machines normally don't have a GPU available. The functionality you're requesting is not available without a GPU in a standard Windows installation. As a workaround, however with largely reduced performance, you can [build](http://www.mesa3d.org/install.html#scons) and install the Mesa3D `opengl32.dll` software rasterizer alongside your program's `.exe` (do not install in the system path!).

Comment: So the idea of my program is that it is given data and makes a video from that. What I am trying to do is have this process all through amazon so that you upload the program and its data and can get a video back instead of having to do the intensive process yourself. Are you saying that without building the rasterizer I won't be able to use opengl on the instance and if I do it will be rather slow?

Comment: @user3565590: OpenGL is not a library but a drawing API. And OpenGL has been optimized for GPU operation. For what you do you hence need a EC2 instance with GPU capabilities. Without a GPU, yes your only option will be fallback to a software emulation, which, yes, will be slow.

Comment: If you see my comment under my question, I am using the GPU EC2 instance, that should be GPU capable I assume. So am I right in thinking that the EC2 is just not detecting the right OpenGL version and I would need some sort of driver to access that?

Comment: @user3565590: Yes, seems like you need to install the drivers. The NVidia homepage is your friend; don't use the Windows integrated driver updater.

Comment: Thanks! looks like in AWS Nvidia provides a version of the EC2 with it's drivers already installed and that solved the issue